# How to run QBitNinja Server locally?

Tags: installation, nbitcoin

I have written a simple program that determines the available balance of a Bitcoin wallet, but it used the public API for **QBitNinja** at http://tapi.qbit.ninja, and everything is working fine, but I wish to run the **QBitNinja** server locally on my PC. I have **Bitcoin-QT** / **bitcoind** installed and fully updated with the latest blockchain data, **NBitcoin** installed in my project, as well as the **QBitNinja** client libraries. However, try as I may, I cannot seem to figure out the steps needed to get the **QBitNinja** server running locally, connecting to **bitcoind** / **Bitcoin-QT**. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am running Windows 10 Pro, and IIS Server that comes with Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. **QBitNinja** is too tightly coupled with Azure, that means **vendor-locked**. See [this issue](https://github.com/MetacoSA/QBitNinja/issues/57) for a recent attempt to decouple it.