# Installing QBitNinja locally

Tags: qbitninja

I am wondering if you found a solution on:
[How to run QBitNinja Server locally?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50817/how-to-run-qbitninja-server-locally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run QBitNinja Server locally?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50817/how-to-run-qbitninja-server-locally)